# How to get pseudo-private attribute through inner class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Test:
    __x = 1
    class C:
        def test(self):
            print(Test.__x)
    c = C()

a = Test()
a.c.test()
```

I get Error Information like this

> AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute '_C__x'

So, is it inner class cannot get access to outer class?
Or It can be using some other techniques?

And this questions comes from reading Learning Python, when author write about CardHolder, a inner class as a descriptor use instance.__name to reach the outer class' attribute, so what is the rule of whether can we access __X attribute?

Thank you for reading my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. *This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class.*

```
class Test:
    __x = 1                     # <= A
    class C:
        def test(self):
            print(Test.__x)     # <= B
    c = C()
```

- In `A` the class is `Test` and therefore `__x` is replaced with `_Test__x`, So, `Test` actually have the attribute `_Test__x`
- In `B` the class is `C`    and therefore `__x` is replaced with `_C__x`, So the attribute you  actually access is `Test._C__x`

To access 'private' `__x` attribute of `Test` class outside Test class definition you should use: `Test._Test__x`

```
print(Test._Test__x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to underscores is the proper way to declare private attributes in Python. Your code would work fine if you changed the name of `__x` to `_Test__x` when you call it from the other class.

```
class Test:
    __x = 1
    class C:
        def test(self):
            print(Test._Test__x)
    c = C()
    def test2(self):
        print self.__x

a = Test()
a.test2()   # prints 1
a.c.test()  # prints 1
```

[This tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_private_attributes_methods.php) goes in the details of it. The rule is: you have to be in the class to call it directly. Subclasses won't work, but methods will.